# Could not decode base64 error when upload images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

I am building Ecommerce in the MERN stack. Products can have multiple images. I use cloudinary to upload images. When I upload more pictures (slightly larger pictures) I get an error `Could not decode base64 error`.

This is my `createProduct` controller:

```
export const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, description, price, color, size, quantity, category } =
    req.body;

  let images = [];

  if (typeof req.body.images === 'string') {
    images.push(req.body.images);
  } else {
    images = req.body.images;
  }

  const imagesLinks = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(images[i], {
      folder: 'products',
    });

    imagesLinks.push({
      public_id: result.public_id,
      url: result.secure_url,
    });
  }

  req.body.images = imagesLinks;

  const newProduct = new Product({
    name,
    description,
    quantity,
    images: imagesLinks,
    price,
    color: JSON.parse(color),
    size: JSON.parse(size),
    category,
    user: req.user.userId,
  });

  const product = await newProduct.save();

  res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json({ product });
};
```

When I upload smaller images, I don't get an error and everything works great. Is there a solution to this problem, something like reducing the image size when uploading, changing it to webp format so that it takes up less space, or something similar?

Comment: Could you please share an example of a Base64 string that allows the file to upload and another Base64 string which reproduces the error?

Comment: @Aleksandar It's too big i can't copy whole thing when i console.log(images)

Comment: @Aleksandar this is just one part https://prnt.sc/0JccKaFV3X1e it's so long.

Comment: Could you please save the output to a temporary file (instead of printing it to the terminal) and then share that file? E.g. in a PasteBin or similar. Also could you please share a screenshot of the error you're receiving?

Comment: @Aleksandar sure, here: https://rentry.co/ob96t

Comment: @Aleksandar and this is error https://prnt.sc/q2y0FLTEJzp4 / https://prnt.sc/1o7KFeI4Wvss

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is that the entire Base64 String you are passing to the upload() method? I ask because I took the Base64 from your output, removed the `data:image/png;base64,` part and decoded the rest, stored the output as a png image locally on the filesystem and then ran `identify -verbose` or `exiftool` on that file and it returns errors - that the file is truncated and not valid.

Comment: Actually, the output from (rentry.co/ob96t) is missing the closing double quote around the Base64 string so it's definitely truncated in that output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250632/discussion-between-aleksandar-and-uros-dioda-rakic).